# jQuery: A widget or plug-in to create text balloons

Tags: jquery, html, css, dhtml, markup-extensions

I need to create some balloons that will contain text messages, similar to what you would see on a BBS or a blog comments area.

I am *not* looking for a tool-tips widget - There will be several per page and they will always be displayed.

My requirements:

- Drop shadows, if possible, using images instead of the `box-shadow` style for compatibility with IE.
- Visual anchor pin or arrow to point to an origin source.
- Size-to-fit contents.
- Can contain markup. I need to have buttons in the balloons.
- Ideally would be applied via `.addClass` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Check out jQuery [qTips](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)

Comment: I don't see an option to have them showing by default (ie. no mouse interaction required) which is what the OP is after.

Comment: @sberry2A..well, you can override the default event for show. if you read the docs you'd see.
http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#show... i.e. event: load for show